# how to segment the colony When I can't use bw image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

I tried to use image processing toolbox to count my colony. I used `imfindcircles` to find the colony and count. But I got some problems:

(1)Due to that my colony could be white and black, I tried to find the colony by using `Bright` or Dark in `ObjectPolarity`, and use a if loop to select which one I finally choose. But the first step of my if loop doesn't really work.

(2) For using `imfindcircles` to find the circle, I found it works for the colony in white, while the method is a disaster for the black colony. I'm kind of desperate now because I can't find other ways to segment the colony.

So finally i need to: label each colony in the plate, count the colony number, calculate each colony size, extract the mean gray value for each colony (the colour).

Thank you very much!!!

So here is my code:

```
im = imread(test.jpeg)
imshow(im)
% to find the colony
[centersBright, radiiBright] = imfindcircles(im,[30 60],'ObjectPolarity','bright','Sensitivity',0.925,'Method','twostage','EdgeThreshold',0.1)
[centersDark, radiiDark] = imfindcircles(im,[30 60],'ObjectPolarity','dark','Sensitivity',0.925,'Method','twostage','EdgeThreshold',0.15)
% to select which one is the correct count. if one of the length(centres) value is lower than 10, I consider it as an error. But if both length(centres) is low than 10, I consider it as a treatment effect and accept the value.
if length(centersDark)<10<length(centersBright)
centers=centersBright
radii=radiiBright
elseif length(centersBright)<10<length(centersDark)
centers=centersDark
radii=radiiDark
else
centers=[centersBright,centersDark]
radii=[radiiBright,radiiDark]
end
% view and label the colony
h = viscircles(centers,radii)
for k = 1:length(radii)
string = sprintf('%d',k)
text(centers(k,1),centers(k,2),string,'color','y','HorizontalAlignment', 'center','VerticalAlignment', 'middle')
area(k)=pi*radii(k)^2
end
```

[image: Sample image]

Comment: Is there any way for you to know before processing the image whether it is a dark or bright colony? That would simplify things greatly, if possible (if not, it should still be doable, but I thought I should ask before delving deeper).

Comment: @Mozglubov Hi! Actually the black and white is one of the phenotype I want to see, and the colony have different scale of darkness. So I would have thousands of images in which colony show different colours. I think it would be difficult to single out the images with colony in a specific colour. :)

Comment: I see; that does complicate the problem a little, since you might erroneously detect circles unrelated to your colonies, so length of the detected set won't necessarily give you the correct answer all the time. Would it be possible to post a few more examples of images to see the range of colours and configurations you are dealing with?

Comment: Also, can you post the output you are currently getting? When I try your code on the images you posted, I don't actually detect any of the colonies on the dark image.

Comment: @Mozglubov Yeah, the black colony is really my problem. I can't get any colonies by using my code, which drives me here to ask questions. I don't know why. I have tried `twostage` and the `phase coding` methods. None of them works. I don't know why i can't add more pictures here, as the system complains. I may try later. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Suggested Solution**

While it's hard to distinguish between the colonies and their surrounding in the black and white version of your input, it is not hard to do so in the hue space by using thresholding.
The reason is that the colonies have a unique hue which is different from their background.
This will be more noticable after converting to [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) space:

[image]
Therefore, I suggest the folowing solution:

1. convert input image to HSV space
2. use thresholding on the hue component.
3. extract connected components
4. Use the connected components which are large enough for the mask
5. perform imclose opertation for cleaning the artifacts

**Code**

```
%reads the image
I = imread('colony2.png');
%convert to hsv
hsvIm = rgb2hsv(I);
%thresholding on the hue space
bwIm = hsvIm(:,:,1) < 0.15;
%find connected components
CC = bwconncomp(bwIm);
%choose only cc with sufficient amount of pixels
numPixels = cellfun(@numel,CC.PixelIdxList);
relevantCC = CC.PixelIdxList(numPixels > 10);
%generate a binary mask with these conencted componants
colonyMask = false(size(bwIm));
for ii=1:length(relevantCC)
    colonyMask(relevantCC{ii}) = true;
end
%perform morpholopical operations for cleaning
colonyMask = imclose(colonyMask,strel('disk',1));

%display result
h = imshow(I); % Save the handle; we'll need it later
set(h, 'AlphaData', ~colonyMask);
```

**Results**

[image]

**Selection of threshold**

The threshold was chosen by choosing the first pick in the histogram of the hue component

```
histogram(hsvIm(:,:,1))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! It looks super good! Thank you! But I still have two questions: (1) After adding the mask (after the `set` command), how should I label and count the colony? I had tried `imfindcircles`, `regionprops`, or even consider to convert the image to `bw` or `gray2bw`. None to them works and all the error massage is about the wrong input type. Where did I got wrong? (2) I really image actually is quite large. So the call `colonyMask`, it took more than half hour for one image? do we have some ways to improve it? or should I reduce all the image size but without changing their colour? Thanks a lot

Comment: 1. you can label it with connected component analysis. Each component has a different lavel.
2. I find it hard to believe that the execution of this code took more than half an hour, regardless to the image size. I think that you may have another chunk of code there, which impact the runtime.